# How to use ViewPager2 with tabs in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

Actually in my app i had an activity which had a include of first fragment in it and then from that fragment i was able to press some buttons to navigate to another fragment, now i would change the activity and add a tablayout from which i will be able to navigate between the three fragments i have, but by reading the documentation i'm can't understand on how i can use the ViewPager2 to show my fragment in it by cliking on the tab.

My activity layout looks like this now:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LetturaActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.VisualStock.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.VisualStock.PopupOverlay" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="8dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/riepilogo"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/testata"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/corpo"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/menu_per_lo_scarico_nuovo_documento_o_riepilogo_articoli"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:tint="@android:color/white" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And then i have three fragment files like this:

```
class LetturaFragment : Fragment() {
...
      override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lettura, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
...
     }
 }

class ArticoliFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articoli, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
...
}
}
```

and the activity

```
class LetturaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lettura)
}
```

How can i use my fragments to navigate in the tab and show them in ViewPager2?

Comment: Hi Mr Kasper Juner if my answer is right then please mark it as useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing which you are asking  i apply in my project its also work for you

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout_home_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/gradianttoolbarbottom"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/custom_menue_bar_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/Orange"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/gray_400_dark" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment_viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_fragment_tabs" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is Kotlin class

```
 class Home_Fragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel
private var myContext: FragmentActivity? = null


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeFragmentViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    myContext=activity
    val viewpagger: ViewPager2 =root.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.home_fragment_viewPager)
    viewpagger.isSaveEnabled=false
    val tabs: TabLayout = root.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.home_fragment_tabs)
    val adapter =MyViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager,lifecycle)
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment1(), getString(R.string.text_Fragment1))
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment2(), getString(R.string.text_Fragment2))
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment3(), getString(R.string.text_Fragment3))
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment4(),getString(R.string.text_Fragment4))
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment5(), getString(R.string.text_Fragment5))
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    viewpagger.adapter =adapter
      TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewpagger) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = adapter.getPageTitle(position)
        viewpagger.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)
    }.attach()
    return root
  }

   class MyViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :  FragmentStateAdapter(manager,lifecycle ){
    private val fragmentList : MutableList<Fragment> =ArrayList()
    private val titleList : MutableList<String> =ArrayList()
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return  fragmentList[position]
    }


    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String){
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
        titleList.add(title)
    }

    fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return titleList[position]
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: how can i set the tab to have selected first item by default? i mean tab 1 and not 0?
by setting         tablayout.getTabAt(1)?.select() it scroll to in when activity is loaded

Comment: for set tab of any possition just right viewpagger.setCurrentItem(2) // pass what ever position you want but type this line of code after TabLayoutMediator(){}.attach()

Comment: Hi Hassnain, one more question, for now i set the tab only with icons and i do it like `        tablayout.getTabAt(0)?.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_inventory)` after .attach() is it the right approach?

Comment: the right approch is to do that kind of things like set text icon or etc before .attach() or if you want to override the default settings then do it after .attach but make shore its not give any null refrence error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use adapter to hook your activity with ViewPager2 object. see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2)

Answer (score 0):

You need an adapter to show these fragments into `TabLayout`.

```
class PagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position){
             0 -> {
                 return LetturaFragment.newInstance(position)
             }
             1->{
                 return ArticoliFragment.newInstance(position)
                 }

        }
        return LetturaFragment.newInstance(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ITEM_COUNT
    }

    companion object {
        private const val ITEM_COUNT = 2
    }
}
```

In your Fragments, define companion object to get the single instance like this

```
class LetturaFragment : Fragment() {
...
      override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lettura, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
...
     }
    companion object {
        private const val ARG_COUNT = "param1"
        fun newInstance(counter: Int?): LetturaFragment {
            val fragment = LetturaFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt(ARG_COUNT, counter!!)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
 }
```

Same for other child fragments

Now in your `Activity`, create a `TabLayoutMediator` to link the `TabLayout` to the `ViewPager2`, and attach it as follows:

```
viewPager.adapter = PagerAdapter(this)
 TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.setText("$position + 1")
            mainBinding.pager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)
        }.attach()
```

For more details read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2)

Answer (score 0):

Use this TabLayoutMediator as following `after you set adapter to ViewPager2`

```
TabLayoutMediator(tab_layout, view_pager) { tab, position ->
                tab.text = fragmentList[position].second
            }.attach()
```